# Jquery's function not working correct for me $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to return data from the server via a JsonResult in mvc. However for some strange reason I cannot pick up my code silently fails. The first alert on the client side succeeds and I do see the output "Got Here" but the second alert is never displayed. Why?

```
    //Server Side
    public JsonResult GetWeightsData()
    {
          PerfomanceMeasureDBDataContext db = new PerfomanceMeasureDBDataContext();
          return this.Json(db.WeightMearsures.Select(x => new { Day =x.Date.ToString(),   Weight = x.Weight }));
    }


    //Client Side
    $(function () {
        $('#ShowChart').click(function () {
            alert("Got Here");
            $.getJSON("/Home/GetWeightsData", null, function (data) {
                alert(data[0].Day);
                var dates = new Array();
                var weights = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    dates[i] = data[i].Day;
                    weights[i] = data[i].Weight;
                    alert(dates[i]);
                }
                showChart(dates, weights);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: place an alert in the `success` callback and see if it ever gets displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP GET requests are denied by default by JsonResult in MVC2+ so that could also be a problem with your code.  Have you tried browsing the "/Home/GetWeightsData" action directly from a browser?

Try:

```
return this.Json(db.WeightMearsures.Select(x => new { Day =x.Date.ToString(),   Weight = x.Weight }), JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

The reason for it is here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks added JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet and that was the fix =D

Answer (score 1):

im not sure but while accessing json you have to `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

```
public JsonResult GetWeightsData()
{
      PerfomanceMeasureDBDataContext db = new PerfomanceMeasureDBDataContext();
      return this.Json(db.WeightMearsures.Select(x => new { Day =x.Date.ToString(),   Weight = x.Weight }),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Firebug to see what's coming out of your controller method?  That linq expression seems odd to me (and the object is spelled wrong) but are you sure you're getting data and it's not just that there's nothing to come back?

Answer (score 0):

Add a .error function to see if there's a problem with the call.

See [jQuery.getJSON docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$.getJSON()`, try `$.ajax()` - add an error handler

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Home/GetWeightsData',
  type: 'post', // Use post, not get
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(){
      alert(data[0].Day);
      var dates = new Array();
      var weights = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          dates[i] = data[i].Day;
          weights[i] = data[i].Weight;
          alert(dates[i]);
      }
      showChart(dates, weights);
  },
  error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
```